# apache nodejs proxy server

Tags: reverse-proxy, node.js, apache2

I have created a node program that it's working on http://example.com:3000/node/index.html and I want to "hide" the port (3000).

I have been reading that I need the a proxy server so I configured apache in different ways but I can't reach what I want.

For example I have used:

```
<VirtualHost myip:8443 myip:8080>     
ServerName example.com    
ServerAlias www.example.com     
DocumentRoot /home/www/  
ProxyPreserveHost On 
ProxyPass /node http://example.com:3000/ 
ProxyPassReverse /node http://example.com:3000/   
</VirtualHost>
```

Please help!!

Comment: Welcome to ServerFault. Have you seen related questions such as https://serverfault.com/q/504735/102173 ?

Comment: Thanks! I have the same but it does not work

Answer (score 1):

Try this Apache configuration:

```
<VirtualHost myip:80>     
     ServerName example.com    
     ServerAlias www.example.com     
     ProxyPreserveHost On 
     ProxyPass /node http://example.com:3000/node 
     ProxyPassReverse /node http://example.com:3000/node
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Thanks worked like charm

Answer (score 0):

As I get from your question, you are quite new to this and I will take advantage of the opportunity to push you towards nginx instead of apache as the former is just nicer to work with when dealing with non-php websites. Additionally, I can just copy-paste you the configuration from my own server. Drop the following into `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/my-site.conf`:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;
        server_name example.com;
        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        }
}
```

Comment: I have Cpanel, so I configured the engintron (nginx) but it did not work...